# i need the proof of P(A∩B)⊇P(A)∩P(B)?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Can anyone please help me get the proof of P(A∩B)⊇P(A)∩P(B) if anyone can show me exactly how its solved i would appreciate it really.
P(A) /// P(B) are power sets of A and B that which is their elements is subsets

Comment: it says for every 2 groups A and B i need to prove this

Comment: The question is, what is $P$? The power set? You mean *sets* instead of *groups*?

Comment: the power set group i think

Comment: Please include the definition of the “power set group” in your post.

Comment: does it make sense now ?

Comment: It is. Note that “$P(A \cap B) \supseteq P(A) \cap P(B)$” means that every element of $P(A) \cap P(B)$ is an element of $P(A \cap B)$. So, all you need to do is to start with an arbitrary element $S \in P(A) \cap P(B)$, and then prove that $S \in P(A \cap B)$. Now, what does, in words, $S \in P(A) \cap P(B)$ mean?

Comment: it means that there is an element S which is common on both the powerset of A and Powerset of B

Comment: And what are the elements of $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ again? Since $S$ is an element of $P(A)$, what does that tell you about how $S$ and $A$ are related? What does $S \in P(B)$ tell you about how $S$ and $B$ are related. It is great that you know what "intersection" means. Now please also remember what "power set" means.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that $A,B$ are sets? If so then it's more common to denote the power set as $\mathcal{P}(A)$ or as $2^{A}$. In any case, we have the following

\begin{align*}
&C \in \mathcal{P}(A\cap B) \Leftrightarrow C \subset A\cap B \Leftrightarrow C \subset A \  \land  \ C \subset B \Leftrightarrow C \in \mathcal{P}(A) \ \land \ C\in \mathcal{P}(B) \Leftrightarrow\\ &C \in \mathcal{P}(A)\cap \mathcal{P}(B) \Leftrightarrow \mathcal{P}(A\cap B) = \mathcal{P}(A)\cap \mathcal{P}(B)
\end{align*}

Comment: A,B are groups bro

Comment: $P$ is entirely common notation for the power set, there is no need to use the curly font, although it is certainly done. Also, if you are pedantic enough to accept $\mathcal P(A)$ but not $P(A)$, then you _really_ shouldn't accept $2^A$, as that's the set of functions $A\to 2$, and not at all the power set. Yes, I know it's very closely related. They are still qualitatively completely different objects.

Comment: @Akim groups are simply sets with an algebraic structure... In this case I don't see the need to consider groups, sorry.

Comment: @Arthur I agree it is common, but even so people confuse that notation with the notation for probability, as you can see from the comments above. And it's not a matter of being pedantic. I simply wanted to offer alternatives to $P$.